# How to get those rows having the equal value and their subscript if there is a [10,1] tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I am new in TensorFlow. If there is a [10,1] tensor, I want to find out all rows with the same value and their subscript.

For example, there is a tensor like `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[1],[2],[3],[4],[6]]`.

By comparing each element in the matrix, it is easy to get a dictionary structure like

`{‘1’: [0,5], ‘2’: [1,6], ‘3’: [2, 7], ‘4’: [3, 8], ‘5’: [4], ‘6’: [9]}` in python, which can record how many times each element occurs in the matrix.
I expect to achieve this result in TensorFlow. Could someone please give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will help if you show an example.

Comment: As an example if you know the value then this will give the subscript.`t = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,55,6,7])
print( tf.where(tf.equal(t,55)).eval() )`

Comment: Hi, Mohan. Thank you so much. I have added more detail to the question description. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: If my answer is partially helpful you may upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a longer method. Still the elements and indices are not associated in a data structure.
Other shorter methods must be there.

```
t = tf.constant([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[1],[2],[3],[4],[6]])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

y, idx, count =tf.unique_with_counts(tf.squeeze(t))

y1, idx1, count1 = sess.run([y,idx,count])

for i in range(len(y1)) :
    print( sess.run( tf.where(tf.equal(t,y1[i]))[:2,-2]))
```

Output is

```
[0 5]
[1 6]
[2 7]
[3 8]
[4]
[9]
```

Comment: Hi, Mohan. Thanks for your comments and help. I am wondering whether it is possible to get unique elements in a tensor like [[1,1],[2,1],[2,1],[3,1]] which will be calculated in a Graph. The expected result is [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]. I really appreciate if you can give any advice.

Comment: AFAIK that is a more involved problem. But you may ask a new question and others may have an easy solution.